# isc-dhcp-server configuration issues

Tags: ipv6, dhcp-server

I use Debian as a router and use dhcpv6 server on ens19 to get the IPv6 address. Now I want to use DHCPv6/SLAAC to assign IPv6 addresses to other devices on ens18. But `dhcpd6.conf` confused me. The IPv6 address prefix obtained from ens19 is dynamic. How should I set `range6`?

/etc/default/isc-dhcp-server:

```
DHCPDv4_CONF=/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf
DHCPDv6_CONF=/etc/dhcp/dhcpd6.conf

DHCPDv4_PID=/var/run/dhcpd.pid
DHCPDv6_PID=/var/run/dhcpd6.pid

INTERFACESv4="ens18"
INTERFACESv6="ens18"
```

/etc/network/interfaces:

```
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

allow-hotplug ens18
iface ens18 inet static
    address 192.168.2.1
    netmask 255.255.255.0

allow-hotplug ens19
iface ens19 inet dhcp
iface ens19 inet6 auto
    dhcp 1
    request_prefix 1
```

Comment: It might be useful to share snippets of the configuration file, in and around the useful bits, rather than a screenshot, especially without context

Comment: @JourneymanGeek ok